# Java Servlet Change Displayed URL

Tags: java, servlets

I'm having difficulty updating a url path to be more readable. The path used to be `https://mywebsite.com/article/EjJKd39`. As you can see the alphanumeric id is not very human readable. I just want to change that to display the title of the article instead (i.e. `https://mywebsite.com/article/change-url-pattern-in-java`).

---

Here is my servlet code.

```
@WebServlet(urlPatterns = {"/article/*"})
public class ArticleServlet extends HttpServlet {

    @Override
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
    throws ServletException, IOException {

        //Logic to retrieve article information from database.

        String redirectUrl = "mywebsite.com/article/" + articleObject.getTitleOfArticle();

        request.setAttribute("article", articleObject);

        response.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_MOVED_PERMANENTLY);
        response.setHeader("Location", redirectUrl);

        request.getRequestDispatcher("/article.jsp").forward(request, response);
    }
}
```

---

As you can see I'm attempting to redirect to my jsp file but under a new url. But what happens instead is I receive a 404 not found error. What am I doing wrong here? I can't seem to figure this out.

---

## Update

My problem is no longer receiving a 404 error. I realized that there was a piece in my code that it sending a 404 error if unable to retrieve the article information from the database. My real problem is that ArticleServlet is getting called after `request.getRequestDispatcher("/article.jsp").forward(request, response)` is called and the URL is requested from the browser. This is causing the code in the servlet to be run again, except this time without access to the parameters that were set. I removed the check for the 404 error and that just allows the servlet to run infinitely. How can I achieve what I want without this happening?

Comment: You're telling the browser to retrieve the new URL. If your webapp isn't actually hosting the article at that URL, then the server is of course going to respond with 404 Not Found when the browser tries to get the new URL. You'll need to change more in your webapp so that the server will be able to serve the article from the new URL.

Comment: I see. I misunderstood what `getRequestDispatcher()` was doing. I realize now that I was sending a 404 error in my logic for retrieving the article information from the database. What's actually happening is that my servlet is being called again and would be getting called infinitely if it weren't for my code that checks if a parameter being passed in through the request object is null or not. So then should I just have this servlet redirect to another servlet, then to my jsp file?

Comment: Okay. So what seems to be happening is when `getRequestDispatcher()` is getting called, it's retrieving the new URL from the browser, but that causes the ArticleServlet to be called again. How can I achieve what I want without calling the servlet infinitely?

Answer (score 0):

You can simply send a redirect with [`sendRedirect`](https://javaee.github.io/javaee-spec/javadocs/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletResponse.html#sendRedirect-java.lang.String-).

> Sends a temporary redirect response to the client using the specified redirect location URL and clears the buffer. The buffer will be replaced with the data set by this method. Calling this method sets the status code to `SC_FOUND` 302 (Found). This method can accept relative URLs;the servlet container must convert the relative URL to an absolute URL before sending the response to the client. If the location is relative without a leading '/' the container interprets it as relative to the current request URI. If the location is relative with a leading '/' the container interprets it as relative to the servlet container root. If the location is relative with two leading '/' the container interprets it as a network-path reference.

```
@WebServlet(urlPatterns = {"/article/*"})
public class ArticleServlet extends HttpServlet {
    @Override
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
    throws ServletException, IOException {
        response.sendRedirect(articleObject.getTitleOfArticle());
    }
}
```

Comment: This does the same thing. It causes ArticleServlet to run infinitely.

Comment: Understood the problem. Then, you can try to use a prefix for hashed links (like `/article/s/EjJKd39` or you need to guess if the link is short hash or full article. Probably, by using regexps. However, I do not think there is a reliable way to distinguish `/article/snfwfoake` (meaningless hash) from `/article/snowflake`.